# How do I iterate of form elements and then pass those to my controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a form that has one text input and many checkbox inputs.  I'm trying to not only pass the data to my controller without a model but also iterate of the many checkboxes and pass those as an array that can be iterated over and passed into a model at a later stage.  Before that, however, I need to grab my form data and pass it to my controller without a model and then work with it from there.

My form code is, shortened for brevity:

```
<form id="ModalFormAddCustomView" asp-action="AddCustomView" asp-controller="Position">
    <input type="text" for="Name" />
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Check1">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Check2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Check3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="Check4">
</form>
```

As you can see it's a simple form, posts to a controller action and contains a single text input and lots of checkboxes.  In my controller, I opted to use `[FromForm]` as a string with a hope I could work with the data after it reached the action.  `content` is always null so that approach isn't working.

```
[HttpPost]
public string AddCustomView([FromForm] string content)
{
    return content;
}
```

Obviously the return type is set to `content` for the purposes of testing and until I get this working.

My question is, how do I post my form data to my controller and also iterate over my checkboxes in the action once I have done this?

Answer (score 0):

You should have a name attribute for each input, because the model binding is based on name.

**View:**

```
<form id="ModalFormAddCustomView" asp-action="AddCustomView" asp-controller="Position">
    <input type="text" name="text" />
    <br />
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Check" value="A">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">A</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Check" value="B">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck2">B</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Check" value="C">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck3">C</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check">
        <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" name="Check" value="D">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck4">D</label>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult AddCustomView([FromForm]string text,[FromForm] string[] Check)
{
    return View();
}
```

**Result:**

[image]